# Creating empty (avoid creating an output at all) when condition is false in if-statement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, if-statement

When using if-conditions with QGIS expressions, the syntax is:

```
if(condition, result_when_true, result_when_false)
```

I would like to get an empty value (avoid creating a value at all) for the third argument, `result_when_false`. It should not be an empty string `''` or `NULL`, but no value at all.

Context: When using an if-condition inside an `array_foreach()` function, for each element with empty output (`result_when_false`), a `''` or `NULL` is added. How to avoid that and add to the array only an element if the condition is true - thus only the `result_when_true` outputs?

What I tried and what works, but is more of a workaround is to use `array_remove_all()` to delete the `''` or `NULL` elements from the array.

However: is there a simpler option to avoid getting an output for `result_when_false`?

Comment: You could try: CASE WHEN conditon THEN result END

Comment: Might have to put it into a slightly larger custom function? test for the condition, set true and false results to variable x and z... (true and false) , but then enter second step to populate array with value set inside of x.... or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that `if()` and `CASE` statements are designed to throw up `NULL` rather than skip a value entirely (so contrary to the comment to your question, not including an `ELSE` still returns a `NULL` for non-matching values) And I think that is the preferable outcome as it would be dangerous otherwise.

Perhaps try `array_filter()` with your condition test, and then if you need to transform the results further you can apply `array_foreach()` to the remaining values.